# Animate UILabel text

Tags: ios, jquery-animate, uilabel, progress

I'm new to iOS programming and i've got a question:
I want to make a kind of custom progress bar. I've created 2 `UIView`s, one above the other and animated the front `UIView` with this code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5f delay:1.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
       [barCima setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 300, value, 30)];
    }
                     completion:nil];
```

But now, I would like to do something more. I want that while the width bar is growing, a `UILabel` appears with the current value. Example: I set de `value` to 300. While the animation is occurring, the `UILabel` is showing the progress until it reaches the 300 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,...,300).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `NSTimer` that fires every one second or so, and a counter. Whenever the `NSTimer` fires, the counter is incremented, and `UILabel`'s text will be updated. It should look like this

```
int _counter; // An instance var

self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
// Be sure you call [self.timer invalidate] when you don't need it anymore

...

-(void)timerFired {
    ++ _counter;
    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", _counter];
}
```

Good luck thought I don't know what you use such a progress bar for!

Comment: Thank you very much!! :) I don't use a progress bar because I want to animate with a UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn. By the way, do you no if it's possible to apply such effect on a progress bar?

Comment: Behind the scene, Core Animation use a [cubic Bezier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B.C3.A9zier_curves), which is represented with a [CAMediaTimingFunction](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CAMediaTimingFunction_class/Introduction/Introduction.html). You can do the same with your progress bar, need a bit of research, some mathematics, but not too hard.